# CodeWars C# Kata stumble

Tags: c#

"The following code is not executing properly, try to figure out why."

```
public class CustomMath {
public static int multiply(int a, string b) {
    return a * b;
}
}
```

Here's my solution:

```
public class CustomMath 
{
    Int i = 1;

    public static int multiply(int a, int b) 
    {
    return a * b;
    }
}
```

I'm still plugging away at it started looking at operator overloading. Still catching the fail so I guess I am still not seeing it or failing to understand something about using operator overloading. Is the operator overloading my only issue or is my return syntax off?

```
using system;

public class CustomMath
{
    public static int operator *(int a, string b) 
    {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

So I'm looking into binary operators, pretty sure my issue is that I am not expressing the int and string properly.

Comment: You don't need the `Int i = 1`, just change `string b` to `int b` and it will work.

Comment: Technically I would make the `CustomMath` class a `static class` (because it is stateless)

Comment: I tried the string b to int b and it still wouldn't work . I will look at making CustomMath a static class as well.

Comment: Static shouldn't matter. String being changed to int should solve it. When you say it's "not working" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @silver It is only possible to overload the multiplication operator if at least one of its operands are of a user-defined type. Otherwise you'd have to put the overload method inside a .NET class.

Answer (score 3):

from the error that you've got you should understand that the function signiture is wrong and you need to change the type of b (string) to be int. so your code would be:

```
public class CustomMath 
{
    public static int multiply(int a, int b) 
    {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you jmallinga for introducing code wars, I'm loving it!

Answer (score 0):

Your operator overload won't work, because in order to overload the multiplication operator, at least one of the operands has to be of a user-defined type.

The thing is, you don't need overloading at all. There are methods in the .NET framework designed specifically to "extract" an integer from a string, which is what you should do before multiplying anything. There are two easy ways of achieving this: `int.Parse` and `int.TryParse`. Just take a look at the MSDN documentation to figure out how they work and choose the best in your specific scenario.

And here is `int.Parse` in action:

```
string s = "5";
int i = int.Parse(s);
int j = i + 10 // At this point j = 15
```